# How to use compensating measures in an CQRS and DDD based application

Tags: validation, domain-driven-design, cqrs, eventual-consistency

Let's assume we host two microservices: `RealEstate` and `Candidate`.

- The `RealEstate` service is responsible for managing rental properties, landlords and so forth.
- The `Candidate` service provides commands to apply for a rental property.

There would be a `CandidateForRentalProperty` command which requires the `RentalPropertyId` and all necessary `Candidate` information.

Now the crucial point: Different types of `RentalProperty`s require a different set of `Candidate` information.

Therefore the commands and aggregates got splitten up:

- Commands: `CandidateForParkingLot`, `CandidateForFlat`, and so forth.
- Aggregates: `ParkingLotCandidature`, `FlatCandidature`, and so forth.

The UI asks the read model to decide which command has to be called.

It's reasonable for me to validate the `Candidate` information and all the business logic involved with that in the `Candidate` domain layer, **but leave out validation whether the correct command got called based on the given `RentalPropertyId`**. **Reason: Multiple aggregates are involved in this validation.**

The microservice should be **autonomous** and it's read model consumes events from the `RealEstate` domain, hence it's not guaranteed to be up to date. We don't want to reject candidates based on that but rather use **eventual consistency**.

Yes, this could lead to inept `Candidate` information used for a certain kind of `RentalProperty`. Someone could just call the `CandidateForFlat` command with a parking lot rental property id.

But how do we handle the cases in which this happens?
The `RealEstate` domain does not know anything about `Candidate`s.

Would there be an event handler which checks if there is something wrong and execute an appropriate command to compensate?

On the other hand, **this "mapping" is domain logic** and I'd like to accomodate it in the domain layer. But I don't know who's accountable for this kind of **compensating measures**. Would the `Candidate` aggregate be informed, like `IneptApplicationTypeUsed` or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

As an aside - commands are usually imperative verbs.  ApplyForFlat might be a better spelling than CandidateForFlat.

The pattern you are probably looking for here is that of an [exception report](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LDW0QWie21s&t=10m48s); when the candidate service matches a CandidateForFlat message with a ParkingLot identifier, then the candidate service emits as an output a message saying "hey, we've got a problem here".

If a follow up message fixes the problem -- the candidate service gets an updated message that fixes the identifier in the CandidateForFlat message, or the candidate service gets an update from real estate announcing that the identifier actually points to a Flat, then the candidate service can emit another message "never mind, the problem has been fixed"

I tend to find in this pattern that the input commands to the service are really all just variations of `handle(Event)`; the user *submitted*, the http request *arrived*; the only question is whether or not the microservice chooses to track that event.  In other words, the "command" stream is just another logical event source that the microservice is subscribed to.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, validation of commands should be performed at the point of command generation - at client side - where read models are available.

Command processing is performed by aggregate, so it cannot and should not check validity or existence of other aggregates. So it should trust a command issuer.

If commands comes from an untrusted environment like public API, then your API gateway becomes a client, and it should have necessary read models to validate references.

If you want to accept a command fast and check it later, then log events like ClientAppliedForParkingLot, and have a [Saga/Process manager](http://blog.jonathanoliver.com/cqrs-sagas-with-event-sourcing-part-i-of-ii/) handle further workflow by keeping its internal state, and issuing commands like AcceptApplication or RejectApplication.

Comment: Thanks, I thought exactly in this direction. But where do you host the logic of calling AcceptApplication or RejectApplication? This is part of domain logic. In the first run we have to check and afterwards accept or reject, but this check has business rules involved. The RealEstate service doesn't know anything about applications at all, thus it doesn't respond with an event.

Comment: Yes, this is a part of domain logic, but it decoupled from domain aggregate. Think of Saga/Process manager as of robot-user that subscribes to any events it needs, builds any state/read models it needs, and can issue commands based on its program. In your case it can subscribe to RealEstate service events to know what it needs about lots, and when it receives application event it can make a decision

Answer (score 0):

I understand the need for validation but I don't think the example you gave calls for cross-Aggregate (or cross-microservice for that matter) **compensating measures** as stated in the Q title.

Verifications like checking that the ID the client gave along with the flat rental command matches a flat and not a parking lot, that the client has permission to do that, and so forth, are legitimate. But letting the client create such commands in the wild and waiting for an external actor to come around and enforce these rules seems subpar because the rules could be made *intrinsic properties of the object originating the process*.

So what I'd recommend is to change the entry point into the operation - to create the `Candidature` Aggregate Root as part of [another Aggregate Root's behavior](http://udidahan.com/2009/06/29/dont-create-aggregate-roots/). If that other Aggregate (`RentalProperty` in our case) lives in another Bounded Context/microservice, you can maintain a list of RentalProperties in the `Candidate` Bounded Context with just the amount of info needed, and initiate the `Candidature` from there.

So you would have

`FlatCandidatureHandler` ==loads==> `RentalProperty` ==creates==> `FlatCandidature`

or

`FlatCandidatureHandler` ==checks existence==> `local RentalProperty data`

==creates==> `FlatCandidature`

As a side note, what could actually necessitate compensating actions are factors *extrinsic to the root object of the process*. For instance, if the property becomes unavailable in the mean time. Then whatever Aggregate holds that information should emit an event when that happens and the compensation should be initiated.